# Returning a complex sql with joins as an array of json objects

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Using a sql query, how can I return an array of json objects that looks like this:

```
{
   "result":[
      {
         "RentBookRegistrationId":1,
         "date":"15-08-2022",
         "PersonName":"Peter",
         "Books":[
            {
               "name":"Ulysses"
            },
            {
               "name":"Hamlet
            }
         ],
         "Processes":[
            {
               "no":1,
               "name":"Online booking"
            },
            {
               "no":2,
               "name":"Reserved beforehand"
            },
            {
               "no":4,
               "name":"Vending machined used"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

From a SQL Server database that looks like this:

Table: **RentBookRegistration**

```
+----+------------+-----------------------------+
| id | date       | person                      |
+----+------------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | 15-08-2022 | {"no": 1, "name": "Peter"}  |
+----+-------- ---+-----------------------------+
|  2 | 16-08-2022 | {"no": 2, "name": "Anna"}   |
+----+------------+-----------------------------+
|  3 | 17-08-2022 | {"no": 1, "name": "Peter"}  |
+----+------------+-----------------------------+
|  4 | 17-08-2022 | {"no": 2, "name": "Mark"}   |
+----+------------+-----------------------------+
```

Table: **BookData**

```
+----+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | rentBookRegistrationId | book                                                      |
+----+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 1                      | {"name": "Ulysses", "author": "James Joyce", "year": 1918}| 
+----+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  2 | 1                      | {"name": "Hamlet", "author": "Shakespeare", "year": 1601} |  
+----+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  3 | 2                      | {"name": "Dune", "author": "Frank Herbert", "year": 1965} |
+----+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  4 | 3                      | {"name": "Hamlet", "author": "Shakespeare", "year": 1601} |  
+----+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  5 | 4                      | {"name": "Hamlet", "author": "Shakespeare", "year": 1601} |  
+----+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Table: **ProcessData**

```
+----+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | rentBookRegistrationId | processUsed                                               |
+----+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 1                      | {"no": 1, "name": "Online booking"}                       | 
+----+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  2 | 1                      | {"no": 2, "name": "Reserved beforehand"}                  |  
+----+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  3 | 1                      | {"no": 4, "name": "Vending machined used"}                |  
+----+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  3 | 2                      | {"no": 1, "name": "Online booking"}                       | 
+----+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  4 | 2                      | {"no": 4, "name": "Vending machined used"}                |  
+----+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  5 | 3                      | {"no": 2, "name": "Reserved beforehand"}                  |  
+----+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

The table layout might seems a bit stupid, but they are simplified to make the question straightforward.

This is how far I've come so far:

```sql
select … from RentBookRegistration R where R.PersonName = 'Peter'
```

Comment: The tables contain JSON data that you want to query and reorganize?  Whoa.  The "Person" data should likely be its own lookup table, and the field RentBookRegistration table should just have a foreign key to the person table.  That would allow the SQL query to get the sub-data you have stored in the JSON and it would reduce the amount of data you're storing since you're storing all the information for each person 1 time for every row they're used on.  Can you change the table structures to be better normalized?

Comment: Thanks Kevin for input. I agree with you. But as I write, this is a simplified scenario. The real system is a data warehouse system and quite complex. E.g. data should not change even if e.g. the person change his name in the future in the 'live' system.

Comment: Another complexity is that we partly support dynamic data, meaning that some tables have columns that are not fixed and can be anything, that is why we have "embedded data" as json (like a document-oriented database system, similar to e.g. MongoDB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't pretty. You are storing JSON data and then want to consume that JSOn data and turn it into different JSON data. Honestly, you would be better off storing your data in a normalised format, and then you can make the JSON more easily.

Saying that, you can do this, but you need to consume your JSON data first, with `OPENJSON` and then turn it back into JSON with `FOR JSON`:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT RBR.id AS RentBookRegistrationId,
               RBR.date,
               p.name,
               (SELECT b.name
                FROM dbo.BookData BD
                     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BD.book)
                                 WITH (name nvarchar(50)) b
                WHERE BD.rentBookRegistrationId = RBR.id
                FOR JSON AUTO) AS Books,
               (SELECT pU.no,
                       pU.name
                FROM dbo.ProcessData PD
                     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(PD.processUsed)
                                 WITH (no int,
                                       name nvarchar(50)) pU
                WHERE PD.rentBookRegistrationId = RBR.id
                FOR JSON AUTO) AS Processes
        FROM OPENJSON(RBR.person)
             WITH (no int,
                   name nvarchar(50)) p
        FOR JSON PATH,ROOT('result'))
FROM dbo.RentBookRegistration RBR;
```

I *assume* you want 1 row per person.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c45d86d974c645bd43f8a864ac9e6270)

Comment: Thank you very much Larnu! It is nearly working for me. **How to I add a where clause that only returns registration rows where name of book is e.g. 'Dune'?**

Comment: Add an appropriate `WHERE` clause, @Mikael .

Comment: I'm trying :-). Could you please assist me. Please take a look at this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cf1d5d73a3855fe1f97c9da14b72a1d0)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't fix the table structure, you can use JSON_VALUE and JSON_QUERY to do what you want to do.  But I recommend fixing the table structures.  Better performance, better resource use, and much simpler queries that are more human readable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16